# How does ggplot indentify if a variable is continuous or discrete?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, ggplot2

How does `ggplot` identify if a variable is continuous or discrete?

I am writing a function to identify it but `ggplot` does it well.
What does the function that accomplishes this in `ggplot` look like?

I am trying to write general function, where we provide just dataframe and function should approximate what variables are discrete and what are continuous...
 My basic function looks like this we provide Dataframe and maximum number of unique values

```
    Classify_numeric <- function(DF = DATA, n_unique) {
  for (i in 1:ncol(DF)) {
    if (is.numeric(DF[ , i])) {
      print(colnames(DF)[i])
      if (length(unique(DF[ ,i])) <= n_unique) {print("Discrete")}
    else {print("Continuous")}
    }
  }
}

Classify_numeric(A, n_unique = 30) # this parameter can be change to whatever or we can 
# write it that n_unique can be some % of lenght of Dataframe
```

and same function just with `is.factor` function

```
    Classify_factor <- function(DF = DATA, n_unique) {
  for (i in 1:ncol(DF)) {
    if (is.factor(DF[ , i])) {
      print(colnames(DF)[i])
      if (length(unique(DF[ ,i])) <= n_unique) {print("Klasifikovatelny")}
  else {print("NEklasifikovatelny")}
    }
  }
}



Classify_factor(A, n_unique = 20)
```

Comment: You'll want to look at the methods for `scale_type()` here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/92099706e0e009fbd58bfa83f7fc8b41deec8877/R/scale-type.R#L59

Comment: ggplot2 is pretty complex. If your actual question is how to deal with specific classes (like "character", "factor", "numeric", ...) the answer is: Use `is.character`, ... and an `if` condition or use the S3 system to create specific methods for these classes. The latter is often preferable.

Comment: If the `class()` of the variable is "factor", "character", or "logical", it's often assumed to be discrete. Anything else is continuous. But it's not easy to answer such general questions. It would be easier to help if you provide specific [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can say for sure what's going on.

Comment: I am trying to write general function, where we provide just dataframe and function should approximate what variables are discrete and what are continuous...   `enter code here`